# Docker error with submission image for Rangl challenge

Tags: python, docker

I am participating in this challenge (https://challenges.rangl.org/) which requires a docker image of my agent to submitted in order to perform evaluation. The procedure is described thoroughly (https://github.com/rangl-labs/netzerotc/tree/main/random_agent_submission#local-testing), but, as I am new to Docker, I get a weird error I am not able to solve, namely, when testing the container (and, thus, also when submitting):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ffede\netzerotc-project\random_agent_submission\test_container.py", line 26, in <module>
    submission = client.containers.run(
  File "C:\Users\ffede\Venv\lib\site-packages\docker\models\containers.py", line 840, in run
    raise ContainerError(
docker.errors.ContainerError: Command 'None' in image 'submission-open-loop:v0.1.0' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

All the solves for this particular error online did not help unfortunately.
I do not know if this is enough information, but I hope so.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In general, just a backtrace is not enough information; also see [ask] in the SO help center.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], with enough source code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, the repo I linked "random agent submission/local testing", to me gives the same error I attached here. So, in theory, the error should be reproducible by this. However, other people were able to submit by using it, so it might be related to some local thing. In that case, though, I do not know what can I upload. Would the docker image (in private) help?